# Using Qt's signals in a non Qt application (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-signals, qcoreapplication

I have a lot of existing code using Qt, and more specifically Qt signals and slots to time specific actions.

Now I need to use this code within a new application which is not a Qt application (and cannot be - I am writing a plugin to visual studio). Anyway - how can I get the existing code to actually intercept the signals and activate the relevant slots?

Do I need to somehow create a dummy Qt application? If so - how do I cause it to process the signals without becoming a blocking loop to the rest of my code?

Comment: Is this resolved now?

Comment: Unfortunately the code below didn't help me. For completely other reasons I had to put this aside and won't be able to get back to it in the near future. So, can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you write something like this, the "Test" message is still printed even though there is no event loop, so this could be a clue:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}
        void testMethod() { emit testSignal(); }

    signals:
        void testSignal();

    public slots:
        void testSlot() { qDebug() << "Test"; }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // QCoreApplication coreApplication(argc, argv);
    MyClass myObject(0);
    QObject::connect(&myObject, SIGNAL(testSignal()), &myObject, SLOT(testSlot()));
    myObject.testMethod();
    // return coreApplication.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

This way, you would still need Qt, but you could avoid having a "blocking" event loop. However, it might be simpler to just rearrange the code from the signal-slot layering to direct calls, depending on how many direct calls you would need to do for a signal emitted.

Comment: Well, not exactly, the event loop is needed for queued connections, but "direct" signal/slots machinery is more akin to .NET multicast delegates, and is mostly unrelated to the event loop.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: true, I tried the code pasted and it works without an event loop.

Comment: Obviously the existing code has the emits and connects, that work perfectly when running within the Qt application. But when I call the same functionality from a different application, I can see the signals are emitted (using a debugger), but the related (and connected) slots are not activated.

Comment: @user3503372: try my code and if it works - it does for me -, the issue is somewhere in your unshown code.

Comment: Sorry - this task got delayed. I hope to get to it tomorrow. I'll update with results, promise. Thanks! Oren

Comment: OK, I just got around to looking at this in more details. I am not sure your solution will work for me. Here's an elaboration of my case:

1) I do not control the main of the application (it could be Visual Studio, in my case).
2) I have quite a lot of classes that emit signals, which should be intercepted by many (other) classes. All those emits and slots are already existing ones. 
3) My problem is that I need to make those happen without my Qt application controlling the events. I tried adding a QCoreApplication instance, but since it does not handle the events, it's useless.

Suggestions?

Comment: @OrenSarid: is threading involved?  Signals/Slots between objects on the same thread should boil down to something more or less equivalent to direct calls - event queues shouldn't be used in this case. But it might help you if you specify explicitly that a `Qt::DirectConnection` should be used.

Comment: @OrenSarid: I am not sure I completely understand you. QCoreApplication does handle non-direct events, but yes, we are discussing direct events. You have not mentioned what is wrong about my answer. You have tried it and something has not worked? If you are referring to threads as Michael is asking, then the default connection type between threads will not be direct, but that is the only case I can think of right now that could cause issues.

Comment: Ansewering both comments:  Yes, there are threads involved, and not, we're not handling direct signals as I have dependencies that cannot go both ways and threads involved. This is why the code uses signals in the first place. Does this help?

Comment: @OrenSarid: are you using qthread for the threads? You could still specify direct explicitly, as queued is the default for threads, but then you would get the slot executed in the emitter's thread, which may differ from the receiver. You would need to take this into account at the design stage.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: No, the code was written using QtConcurrent::run and QFuture. I cannot change that (not my code). The signals emitted by this code are not activating their slots as I have no qt application running.

Comment: @OrenSarid: You are asking whether you can use Qt, but then you say, you cannot rewrite and have to preserve the Qt code. I am all kinds of lost, sorry. Hope someone can help you.

Comment: Then I must have explained myself badly. I have existing Qt code, which should be left as it is as I am not its only user. That said, I am using it compiled into a DLL used in a non-qt application, unlike the other users. This makes me the only one not able to use the already-code signals and slots. And this is why I started the thread in the first place.  Therefore, I am still looking for a way to process those signals and slots from my DLL, which will be loaded by IDEs like Visual Studio/eclipse. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when using ASIO and Qt together. The solution I have found is to make a Broker object, and run the Qt and ASIO loops on their own threads. The Broker is the target for emit calls to the ASIO message queue, and the emitter to the Qt message queue. Take care of the syncronisation/data copying in the Broker.